# How to turn off ESLint in PhantomJS unit tests, in a webpack project generated by vue-cli

Tags: javascript, webpack, phantomjs, vuejs2, eslint

NOTE: Thanks to [@loganfsmyth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785065/loganfsmyth) I realized that this question is rather trivial and that I had the wrong idea how is the ESLint configured. But the question and solution might be useful for someone else anyway.

---

Because I am running unit tests rather often and the linting takes a while and produces a lot of output, I'd like to turn off ESLint when running unit tests.

Here's the relevant part of `webpack.base.conf.js`:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        enforce: "pre",
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')],
        options: {
          formatter: eslintFriendlyFormatter
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: I think you'll need to clarify what issue you are having. ESLint checks code for formatting, `env` with `phantomjs: false` makes sure your own code is not using any of PhantomJS's APIs, it has no effect on when linting is executed. When that runs in entirely dependent on your own test-runner setup, which you haven't talked about. What actually runs ESLint for you right now?

Comment: I used vue-cli to generate everything. I am using webpack, karma, mocha and sinon. I thought that env setting is telling eslint in which case to execute linting (e.g. when running in browser). What file do you need to see?

Comment: What is the issue you are actually trying to resolve? What drove you to file this issue? What specifically is going wrong when you run your unit tests that make you not want to run linting? If `eslint` has ready your `eslintrc` file, it's already running, it's way too late at that point to tell it not to run. I don't know how `vue-cli` configures things unfortunately. Maybe others can chime in.

Comment: I usually do a split screen tdd, tests are running on every save. I am trying to teach myself good code conventions, but eslint produces a lot of output and it hurts the productivity when it runs all the time. I am new to modern Javascript, I am sure it will improve over time. I will edit the question.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Thanks for pushing me the right direction, it was very simple when I realized what does the configuration in .eslintrc do and that I have to look before this config is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is trivial:

Because the ESLint is setup in the `base` configuration, it is inherited in all the other environments.

Simply move this rule in the same section under any environment you want the linting to run and omit it in each environment you don't want it to run.